# php - Pass even if the selectpicker is empty

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach ($activities as $key => $activity_list):?>                                                      
<select class="selectpicker form-control" name="characteristics[<?= $key ?>][]" id="characteristics" multiple="" data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98">
        <option value="Visual">Visual</option>
        <option value="Dimension">Dimension</option>
        <option value="Chemical">Chemical</option>
        <option value="Mechanical">Mechanical</option>
</select>                                               
<?php endforeach;
```

Example:

3 select tags are generated by the above foreach with keys(0,1,2).

The problem is when the user is not selecting the second select tag it is passing only two arrays and it's saving the third array values in the second row place in the db.

In the below print it's getting only the two select tag values even though there are three select tags.

```
$characteristics = array_values($this->input->post('characteristics'));
print_r($characteristics);

Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Visual 
        [1] => Dimension 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => Chemical 
    ) 
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is no form value, you won't get it. But can check isset in your controller.

Comment: You _have_ all the information you need though here - the key you provided in the field name, will allow you to recognize that only for the first and the third field, there was actually a value submitted. You just _lost_ that proper key here, because you used `array_values`, and that re-indexes the array numerically.

Comment: name="characteristics[<?= $key ?>][]"  second brackets are empty

Comment: @AlivetoDie Can we pass an empty array or something if it's not selected. I want to use array_values for another reason.

Comment: The reason why providing a “default” option does not work as desired here, is that the select fields have the `multiple` attribute set. Only selects without that, submit their first option as the default selected one, with `multiple` select however, only the options explicitly selected by the user, will be submitted. _“I want to use array_values for another reason”_ - that makes very little sense. The array key is the _only_ thing, that allows you to properly associate the values with their meaning - and by using `array_values`, you are _destroying_ that association.

Comment: _“I'm looking for adding a new array or something for the unselected select tags”_ - then merge it with a default array, that contains an empty array(?) for each key, or something like that.

Comment: @CBroe Can't we add an empty array for the not selected select tags?

Comment: Automatically, based on how HTML forms and PHP work together? No. Manually? Yes, I just gave one possible way to do that with the previous comment.

Comment: @CBroe How to achieve that? Can you please post the answer for that?

Comment: (You _could_ add a hidden input field with the same name before each select field, but than you would get an extra entry at the beginning of _all_ those sub-arrays, both for the select fields the user chose options in, and the ones they did leave alone - so then you would have to skip that first entry in all further processing … not sure that’d actually make things easier.)

Comment: Get all your necessary keys using `array_keys($activities)`. Then loop over that, check if your data array has an entry set under the current key. If not, add an empty array under that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go with 2nd way what suggested by @CBroe.

Get keys of coming array and add missing keys data yourself.

Do like below:

```
$arrLength = count($characteristics);
$rangeArray = range(0,$arrLength);

foreach($rangeArray as $rangeArr){
    if(!isset($characteristics[$rangeArr])){
        $characteristics[$rangeArr][] = [];
    }
}
sort($characteristics);

$characteristics = array_values($characteristics);
print_r($characteristics);
```

Sample hardcode example: https://3v4l.org/jZTqQ